# How do I profile OpenIdConnectAuthentication in ASP.NET for performance issues?

Tags: asp.net

I suspect that OpenIdConnectAuthentication is causing performance problems in my ASP.NET (not core) application. How would I profile it to determine if that's really the cause?

I am using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect 4.0.1.0.